# given an area, calculate the sides of a rectangle so they are similar length

Tags: algorithm, width, area

The area is an integer.

Given an area, I want to draw squares representing square meters. So for example given a 30 area, I want to draw a rectangle of 6 x 5 or 5 x 6, but not one of 2 x 15, because that would look too long and thin.

I can also accept drawing less squares in the last row, so for example for a 33 area, I can draw 6 x 5 rectangle and a last row of 3 squares.

I tried prime factorization but for example for 597 I get 3 and 199, too long and thin.

I tried quadratic function, using the formula

```
0 = x^2 + x - area
```

So I would use the positive solution as one of the sides, and the other side would be 1 unit longer.

But I don't get an integer result, and rounding up or down modifies the resulting area.

Any other ideas? Is there a known algorithm for this? 
This question: [Fastest way to calculate rectangle sides from area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749199/fastest-way-to-calculate-rectangle-sides-from-area) was closed but I think this is a valid question.

Answer (score 2):

Compute the square root of the area; round it up and down for your sides.  If that is too small, bump the smaller value up 1.

Examples:

- sqrt(30) = 5.???, so we get 5 & 6, and 5x6=30
- sqrt(36) = 6, so we get 6x6=36
- sqrt(48) = 6.???, so we get 6 & 7, and 6x7=42.  Bump it to get 7x7=49, and the last row has 1 square (which you said was acceptable).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you prefer the nearest shape to square, You can start with **Integer part of sqrt(area)** and add width and height one by one:

```
width=[sqrt(area)] // Integer part of Square root
heigh=width
while ((height*width)<area){
   if (height<width)
          {height=height+1}
   else 
          {width=width+1}
}
```

Comment: While this may actually work, please add some more information to your answer. Also, the loop is irrelevant, though. `sqrt(x) * sqrt(x) = x = sqrt(x²)`

Comment: Thank you both.
The start value of width is Integer part of sqrt(area) not the exact sqrt. So the loop works if area is not a exact square @creamopy